# DocuSign transformPdfFields

Tags: docusignapi

I have a pdf that I need to create and attach the pdf in the envelope that has custom fields in it. These fields are DocuSign fields names. But transformPdfFields is not working. All I get is a document with no fields.

Please see code.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<status>sent</status>
<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Embedded Signing example</emailSubject>
<documents>
    <document>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <name>C:\Users\Desktop\Test Projects\DocuSign\Test.pdf</name>
        <transformPdfFields>true</transformPdfFields>
    </document>
</documents>
<recipients>
    <signers>
        <signer>
            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            <email>me@me.com</email>
            <name>Mike Rosey</name>
            <defaultRecipient>true</defaultRecipient>
        </signer>
    </signers>
</recipients>
```

Comment: What are the name values of the fields on the document?  The "DocuSignSignHere" kind?

Comment: Two are docusign specific: DocuSignCompany, eSignFullName and two are my specific: FirstName, lastName

Comment: @Jameson did you ever get this resolved?